# Python Urllib2.HTTP error: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Tags: python, facebook, urllib2, urllib

I have a piece of code that calls facebook API like this:

```
ID = str(cell.value) #ID comes from an excel spread sheet
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://graph.facebook.com/' + urllib.quote(ID) +'/comments?summary=true&limit=0'))
Comments_count = int(data.get("summary").get("total_count"))
```

However, I am getting error on certain URLs.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "FBS.py", line 50, in <module>
    data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen('http://graph.facebook.com/' + urllib.quote(ID) +'/comments?summary=true&limit=0'))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 410, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 523, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 448, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 531, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.get_full_url(), code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

I already tried using Urllib.quote(ID), but I still have the same issue.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Comment: On *what* URLs? What are these ids? And why do you think to need to quote the value?

Comment: these IDs are facebook IDs. For example, 450170755110703, it would be
http://graph.facebook.com/450170755110703/comments?summary=true&limit=0

The reason why I used urllib.quote is because I read it from another thread saying that it solved the issue for some people.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass access token to graph api to get this information. I suggest you use a sdk like [this](https://github.com/pythonforfacebook/facebook-sdk) to access graph api